# Windows 8 Metro and Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Will it be possible to use the Google Analytics JavaScript library (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/) for the Windows Metro JavaScript based application to trace views accessed by user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, if a JavaScript library you want to use is on a CDN or a server external to your app, the answer is no, as Windows apps written with HTML/JavaScript cannot load external JavaScript libraries...if you try, a security exception will occur.

Many libraries will work fine if you copy the JS file into your project and run it locally. For example, jQuery works just fine this way. I have not tried the Google Analytics library, so you might just want to test it out and see if it will work with a local copy.

Something else to consider, however, is that unlike a web site, a Windows app written in HTML/JavaScript may occasionally be offline, in which case, a library written with the assumption of network connectivity would likely not work. So in this particular case, you might not get the data that you're hoping for.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

we tried http://w8ga.codeplex.com/ (w8ga) to work with GA in our win8 js app.
Currently W8GA seems doesn't support html/js. Also I have no idea why developer didn't mension it( it's supports only c#/xaml metro app )

So, we found another way to do it; Look for cobra Tab 's answer at the bottom of this page: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/f81ebbb9-d711-40f1-8a82-9aed44e2d8fe/

And finally, we are waiting Adobe's Omniture sdk: 
http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/sc/appmeasurement/winrt/index.html#Developer_Quick_Start

Hope these answers helps...

Comment: just found this answer/ I'm author of w8ga, just updated the documentation, thank you for your input. I know it's late, however, it's better then never  :)

Answer (score 1):

We're using the free version of [markedup](https://markedup.com/winrtanalytics) in our applications with great success. In addition to simple page views it shows you some app specific numbers like number of installs, exception details, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the [Google Analytics SDK for Windows 8 and Windows Phone](http://googleanalyticssdk.codeplex.com). It is built as a WinRT component and therefore supports both JS & Xaml Win8 apps.

Full disclosure: I am the author of this SDK; I built it for my own app and decided to open source it. There are other frameworks out there but AFAIK, none of them support the new GA universal analytics protocol so they only work with older GA properties and don't support all the cool new features GA recently added just for apps.

Comment: Is there a tutorial or documentation on how to integrate this?