# Integrating google analytics in Windows 8 HTML5/Javascript Game

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, google-analytics

I have developed a Windows 8 HTML5/Javascript Game.

Now, I am trying to integrate Google Analytics into the game to track the events of the player.

Firstly, I tried to integrate it Just like we integrate in websites, But it didn't work.

Then, I found [this](http://www.benfarrell.com/2012/11/09/moving-your-jquery-and-google-analytics-based-web-app-to-windows-8/) solution after some searching.

But even after implementing this solution as it is, I have not been able to track the events in my game.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/f81ebbb9-d711-40f1-8a82-9aed44e2d8fe ?

Comment: @Xyroid one of the answer in the link you provided is quite similar to what i had implemented using the link given in my question. So, Yes, I have checked that approach, But Still the tracking status on the GA portal says **Unknown**.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/11652776/65899. Check my solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18215685/65899